# How To Validate Form Field Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to validate my form phone field to prevent users from entering the same numbers in my javascript.

If the number provided by the user matches with the same numbers in my javascript, They will get a warning and the form would not submit.

However, I noticed that my code below shows the warning whether the numbers match or not.

I need corrections to know what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Code below;

```js
 $('.validate').hide();
    $('body').on('blur', '#phone', function() {
        $('.validate').hide();
        isphone($(this).val());
    });

    function isphone(phone) {
        if (phone === "1234" || phone === "23456"){
            $(".validate").show();
         
        } else {
            $(".validate").hide();
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<form action='' method='POST' id="submitForm" >
   
 <input type="phone" name='phone'  required=''  id="phone" placeholder="0000-000-0000"/>

 <div class="validate"><span style="color: red;"><b>Please enter a valid phone!</b></span></div>
 
 <button href='/' type='submit' id="submitForm">Process</button>
 
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work.
I move the changes for hiding and showing `$('.validate')` to the `isphone` function, and removed that `done` variable that wasn't doing anything useful (used `if...else` instead).
Also, don't use `document.getElementById` if you're already using JQuery.

```
    $('.validate').hide();
    $('body').on('blur', '#phone', function() {
        $('.validate').hide();
        isphone($(this).val());
    });

    function isphone(phone) {
        if (phone === "1234" || phone === "23456"){
            $(".validate").hide();
        } else {
            $(".validate").show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked for me. But will this prevent form submission if the user does not correct the errors? I was thinking return o; or return false; was needed?

Comment: The form isn't submitted at any point here. You should set up another mechanism somewhere else for submission, with a button.
Also if you enjoyed my answer, upvote is always appreciated ;)

Comment: Can you please see my question again, I updated it with your code and added a button this time. I will appreciate it if you can figure out a way to prevent the form submission until the user corrects their error. Thanks.

Comment: That's a different task. 
You've updated your code, the logic works, now you need to create another function that checks if what's in the phone field is valid, and submits the form if it's valid.

Comment: Please, can you help me with that or this is as far as you can go?

Comment: It wouldn't be truly helping if I wrote it for you.
I recommend you look into https://api.jquery.com/submit/ and create a function to submit your form.
You're very close.

Comment: Alright, Thanks.